# how can I create a fake promise that answers with a done function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, which does not work if vID=0 because ajax.done does is not a function:

```
if (vID > 0) {
  var ajax = CallPHP('GET', 'grid_main.php', "idquery=7&trkbid=" + vID);   
} else {
  // Here I need a fake ajax so that the following code will work
  var ajax=new Promise();
};

ajax.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
 // do something
}
```

how can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Why you need to do that ? you can put the ajax.done in the if instead. You could make a fake object with a done method that does nothing : `var ajax = { done: () => {} }` but that does not make a lot of sense to me

Comment: because I have the same things to do in both cases and I did not want to put them in a function, then call the same function on both cases. I was wondering if I could avoid that like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More logical is make a function and call that.

```
function nextStep(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
 // do something
}

if (vID > 0) {
  var ajax = CallPHP('GET', 'grid_main.php', "idquery=7&trkbid=" + vID).done(nextStep);   
} else {
  nextStep({});
};
```

You can not use a promise since jQuery's Ajax object is not a promise. It would have to look something like

```js
var ajax = {
  done: function(method) {
    method({});
  }
};

ajax.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

You could use jQuery's deferred

```js
var ajax = $.Deferred().resolve({});

ajax.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes that works. I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the same without creating a function "nextStep" and writing the code just once.

Comment: Why would you be writing the code more than once. Naming the function is no different than shoving it into the done method. The other solution is uglier. Gave you 3 solutions.